# Inject JAXBContext into spring

Tags: spring, jaxb, code-injection

I am trying to inject a `JAXBContext` into spring application context, by:

```
<bean id="jaxbContext" class="javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext" factory-method="newInstance">
  <constructor-arg type="java.lang.Class" value="com.package.MyClassName"/>
</bean>
```

It throws an exception:

> No matching factory method found: factory method 'newInstance'

And I also try :

```
<bean id="jaxbContext" class="javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext" factory-method="newInstance">
  <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="com.package"/>
</bean>
```

And It throws an an exception:

> javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "com.package" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index
>   I did put a jaxb.index file inside the package "com.package" and has a single line "MyClassName" in the file.

Comment: I can instance JAXBContext by JAXBContext.newInstance(MyClassName.class); but not able to inject it using the same way.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

@Tomasz's answer is the solution I'd recommend, but if you want to stick with `JAXBContext`, then the reason your first example failed is that the [`static getInstance()` method on `JAXBContext`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/) doesn't take a single `Class` argument, it takes a vararg list of them. So you need to inject a list, not a single class:

```
<bean id="jaxbContext" class="javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext" factory-method="newInstance">
  <constructor-arg value-type="java.lang.Class">
    <list>
       <value>com.package.MyClassName</value>
    </list>
  </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Comment: Actually `getInstance()` does accept a single `Class` argument ([see docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.html)), so something like `<constructor-arg><value type="java.lang.Class">com.package.MyClassName</value></constructor-arg>` would also work.

Answer (score 11):

Have you tried Spring OXM? The last line is important, namespaces are for reference only:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-1.5.xsd">

    <oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="marshaller" contextPath="com.package"/>
</beans>
```

See [8.4. XML Schema-based Configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/reference/html/oxm.html#d0e5649). Yu'll also need `spring-oxm` on your classpath.

Comment: Hey Tomasz. Thank you for your reply. I am using spring 2.5, which doesn't supoort OXM. But it's a solution to who using spring 3.0

Comment: The problem with using oxm namespace is that I haven't found a way to inject JAXBContext properties, e.g. for using a custom Accessor to process Hibernate beans and skip lazy relations.

Answer (score 2):

this will resolve the problem for jaxb.index file or ObjectFactory problem in spring env. provide the value of the package where the classes are their which generate the xml

```
    <bean id="marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
        <property name="packagesToScan" >
            <value>com.adarsh.spring.integration.entities</value>
        </property>
   </bean>
```